# problemas al cambiar el color de un boton desde el codigo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo una windows form donde diferentes subpestañas son activadas mediante botones, quiero hacer que cuando se le de click a cada boton a parte de abrir su respectiva pestaña este cambie de color (para demostrar que se esta en su pestaña), cuando se cambie de pestaña el boton anterior debe volver a su color anterior(transparent) y al que se le dio debe cambiar (green)

```
 private void btnTemas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnTemas.Normalcolor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            if (btnTransparencia.Normalcolor == System.Drawing.Color.Green)
            {
                btnTransparencia.Normalcolor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent; 
            }
            if (btnvoice.Normalcolor == System.Drawing.Color.Green)
            {
                btnvoice.Normalcolor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            }
            if (btnAudioPanel.Normalcolor == System.Drawing.Color.Green)
            {
                btnAudioPanel.Normalcolor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            }
            if (btnAbout.Normalcolor == System.Drawing.Color.Green)
            {
                btnAbout.Normalcolor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            }
        }
        private void btnTransparencia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnTransparencia.Normalcolor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            if (btnTemas.Normalcolor == System.Drawing.Color.Green)
            {
                btnTransparencia.Normalcolor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            }
            if (btnvoice.Normalcolor == System.Drawing.Color.Green)
            {
                btnvoice.Normalcolor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            }
            if (btnAudioPanel.Normalcolor == System.Drawing.Color.Green)
            {
                btnAudioPanel.Normalcolor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            }
            if (btnAbout.Normalcolor == System.Drawing.Color.Green)
            {
                btnAbout.Normalcolor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            }
        }
```

Originalmente lo hice usando variables que almacenaran los botones para que el codigo no fuera tan largo, al ver que no servia decidi hacerlo como esta ahí.
Tambien intente cambiando el (.backColor) pero simplemente no hacen lo que deberia.

Comment: Seguro que con Button1.BackColor = Color.Green no cambia????, ademas te recomiendo que uses una variable donde asignes el boton seleccionado actual y asi te es mas facil seguirle el rastro y no tienes que preguntar n veces solo 1

Comment: Lo intenté  tanto con el .backColor como almacenando el botón en variables pero no funcionó

Comment: hola Jhoan, primero que nada cuando quieres que lo haga si pasando el mouse o haciendo click o en la afectación de un datagrid... no se alguna pista

Comment: puedes poner el ejemplo del codigo que no te funciono con el backColor, me imagino que estas usando el button nativo de windows forms no???

Comment: @Samael como dije en el primer parrafo, cuando haga click en cada botón

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas estoy usando el flatButton de Bunifu, no pensé que eso represenataría un problema ya qu epor lo que veo funcionan practicamente igual

Comment: Has tratado de cambiarle el fondo desde el diseñador a ver que sucede, jugando con las propiedades de tipo color????

Comment: mm no he utilizado bunifu, encontre esto por la red a ver si te sirve [Aquí](https://bunifuframework.com/topic/how-to-use-tabs/)

Comment: Encontre el error!! Aunque creo que mas que error mio es de visual studio, por algun motivo si no pongo la parte de cambiar pestaña el metodo entero de click jamas se ejecuta. Solo agregué "tabTemas1.Visible = true;" al final de varios de ellos y ahí si empezo a cambiar los colores. Supongo que necesita de una accion auxiliar o algo asi.
Gracias a todos!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor que podes hacer es tenes una variable con el ultimo boton y un solo metodo, por ejemplo

```
private Button ultimoBoton = boton1; // Aca asigna el boton que empieze con color, en caso que no exita ninguno, asigna null

private void ClickBoton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//Recorda que si asignas ultimoBoton en null, verifica que este no sea null, para evitar nullReference
ultimoBoton.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
(sender as Button).BackColor = Color.Green;
ultimoBoton = (sender as Button);
        }
```

Asigna este metodo a TODOS tus botones, no olvides eso